# Do the lists have to be ordered list.SequenceEqual() function to work correctly?

Tags: c#, list, .net-core

As the Title states do the lists have to be ordered for the SequenceEqual function to work?

Comment: If they aren't the sequences are *not* equal. `SequenceEqual` is an extension to `IEnumerable<>`, not `List` anyway

Comment: The function will work correctly: it will return false.

Comment: @programNoob why the question? What are you really trying to do? If you want to check whether two lists contain the same items irrespective of order, you should probably look to set collections, like HashSet

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have 2 lists of objects, the order the objects in both lists is random, but if both lists contain the same objects regardless of the order I want to return true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2) is an extension to IEnumerable, not just List.

As its documentation explains, it returns  :

> `true` if the two source sequences are of equal length and their corresponding elements are equal according to the default equality comparer for their type; otherwise, `false`.

The enumerables don't *have* to be sorted for the method to work correctly, ie not throw.

If the two lists contain the same items in different order though, it will return false. Which is exactly what it's expected to do. It will work even if the enumerables contain duplicate values because it doesn't really care where the values are, only what the corresponding values are.

If you want to check whether two lists *without duplicates* contain the same items no matter the order, you should use a HashSet and its [SymmetricExceptWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.symmetricexceptwith?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. If the hashset contains any items after the call, it means the lists don't contain the same items. Eg:

```
var set1=new HashSet<int>(someList1);
set1.SymmetricExceptWith(someList2);
if (set1.Count>0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not the same values! Here are the differences:");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",set1));
}
```

Comment: «If the two lists contain the same items in different order though, it will return true.» Do you mean false?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias oops